# Shadow volume implementation

Tags: java, opengl, shader, lwjgl, shadow

I need some help implementing shadow volumes into my demo.  I already found some GLSL shader files and I've already created a proper shader loader. All I need is to know how to implement it the right way.
I am using **LWJGL 2.9.0**.

**shadowvolumes.vs**

```
void main()
{
    vec4 lightAngle;
    vec4 pos;
    lightAngle = normalize(gl_Vertex-gl_ModelViewMatrixInverse*gl_LightSource[0].position);
    if (dot(gl_Normal,lightAngle.xyz)<0.0) 
    {
        if (gl_Color.r>0.0)
            pos = gl_Vertex+lightAngle * 10.0;
        else
            pos = gl_Vertex;
    }
    else {
        pos = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    }
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix*pos;
}
```

**shadowvolumes.fs**

```
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0);
}
```

Just give as much advice as possible.

Comment: This could give you some basic information : http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-16-shadow-mapping/

Comment: @Grimmy The linked article talks about shadow mapping (not shadow volume), which is a different technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have is an extrusion vertex shader.

All it does is checking if your triangle is facing or not the light (the `dot` instruction). If it isn't then the `w` coordinate is set to zero ( `vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)` ) so that the vertex is projected at infinity. Otherwise if a cpu computed flag is non-zero (`gl_Color.r`) then the vertex is extruded away from the light source following `lightAngle` (`lightAngle` is the direction from light toward the vertex rather than an angle).

This shader is only responsible of building a volume where every fragment inside it will be in shadow.

The more interesting parts will be to compute the lit silhouette by the caster and to use a stencil buffer to test whether a fragment is inside or outside the volume.

[HeHe tutorial 27](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/shadows/16010/) is an excellent and easy to follow tutorial for shadow volumes.

[GPU Gems](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch09.html) has an article with tricks to have a faster and artifact free shadow volumes.

Comment: The NeHe tutorial use a lot of deprecated methods, so it's really bad to use that for learning how to do shadow volumes.

Comment: @Vallentin Very good point: most NeHe tutorials were written at the time of T&L. However, to learn the basics of a z-pass shadow volume some cpu code and fixed function stencil buffer will do the trick (these aren't deprecated). Because of this I figured mentioning the old but super cool NeHe tutorial where the literate programming style helps a lot

Comment: Yea I agree, using deprecated methods is good for learning, though it would be good to tell that in the answer, so people are aware of the use of deprecated methods.